# Creating Interactive Map Using Something Other Than Google?

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, php, html

I have a Roleplay Forum, and I would like to add a map of my Roleplay World to the website.

I would like my map to be clickable, and have each location take you to a place on the forum. I don't know coding outside of basic basic [phpBB](https://www.phpbb.com/) prosilver.

I want the map to be an image, a large one, where you can scroll around the element like a map and then click on a city, location or land and it takes you there on the forum.